# lsof - how to cross - compile for ARM architecture

Tags: arm, cross-compiling, glibc, lsof

**Inb4 use busybox.**
 I need to have the flag `HASSECURITY` disabled. In busybox the flag is enabled, and  I do not see any way to change the compilation flags of buysbox'es components(however if there is a way to do it - i would like to learn about it)

I have been trying to cross - compile the **lsof-4.87** from source using **arm-linux-androideabi-gcc-4.8** provided in the adt bundle (20140321). Before running the Configure script i export the environment variables:

```
export LSOF_ARCH="armv7l"
export LSOF_CC=${HOME}/NDK/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140321/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
export LSOF_CCV=4.8
```

However during the Configure script execution I still get the error message:

```
Cannot determine C library type; assuming it is not glibc
```

Would you have any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Since Android provides bionic instead of glibc it might not be trivial to compile with ndk.

Comment: hmmm... yet it is possible. Guys from busybox made it somehow.
inb4 is for replying to the obvious answer before it is asked.

Comment: I just found on xda-developers forum that CodeSourcery's toolchain uses it's own glibc. Might be worthy a shot! Thanks!

Comment: You maybe able to statically link with *uClibc* or some other small library (and the appropriate compiler).